# A lot of components are re-rendering with every single operation

Tags: reactjs, redux

The performance of my React app is very poor and if you select "Highlight updates" in Chrome you'll find basically every single component re-renders with every move you make.

Open a simple modal? Everything in the app re-render, right down to the FontAwesome icons.

Click anywhere on the screen? Everything re-renders.

I've added really aggressive `shouldComponentUpdate`s to basically every component.
I've used `DeepDiff` to check what's causing the updates (nothing is. The props/state are basically always the same).

What else can I check to try and solve this? There's nothing fancy at all going on, and most of the time it doesn't even involve Redux or anything like that.

Comment: What versions of react and react-redux are you using?

Comment: React 16.4.0, and Redux 5.0.7

Comment: Any particular reasons you can't upgrade to the latest versions? I don't know about react-redux v5 but I know v6 had a lot of performance issues causing aggressive re-rendering in some applications. This also included false-positives in the debugger showing re-rendering where there was none.

Comment: It might be happening because you have set State in parent component and due to which every child component is re rendering

Comment: React works hierarchically. You can look into the smallest component and check why *it* is rerendering, disregarding everything else. For example, you might be passing your redux state to all your components, making them render when anything in it changes.

Comment: Just from general "help all my components re-render" it's hard to diagnose the reason for it. The points to look for are definitely your store provider and any other top level components and context providers that frequently change state. Also `shouldComponentUpdate` is most likely not a fix for your problem. You should use it sparingly. We develop some decently sized react apps and nearly never need it.

Comment: I know, I didn't want to have to use `shouldComponentUpdate` so much - I just don't really know what else to do. 99% of my updates have no state/prop changes at all. `why-did-you-update` somehow clocked ~6000 unnecessary updates in the first 5 seconds of starting the app...

Comment: @MitchEff I'm afraid with at least a little insight into the actual code it is impossible to name a concrete thing. This is only a guessing game. How are most of your components connected to the store? Are there any actions dispatched? Are you using `setInterval` or the like anywhere? Do you use context providers?

Comment: Sigh. I know, I would've said the same - I'm just not sure where to start. Is it uncouth to ask if anyone wants to hop on CodeMentor and I'll pay for some assistance?

Comment: Without any details of your code, I can only advice you to debug re-render logic inside `componentDidUpdate` in a brute-force way - check if there is any change inside each of your props and state which can cause the issue. Start from the very top component down, and solve one scenario at a time (e.g. opening modal) to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @MitchEff If you want to I would have a short look at it but my schedule only allows for it after 7 pm Berlin time.

Comment: @MitchEff You said even a click anywhere triggers updates. Do you have any event handlers attached to a DOM node high up the tree? Something that listens e.g. to click or pointer movement events and propagates those down?